# Time complexity of operations in SortedList - Python

Tags: python, sortedlist, sortedcontainers

What is the time complexity of operations in SortedList implementation of sortedcontainers module?
As I understand, the underlying data structure is an array list. So does insertion takes `O(n)` time since the index can be found in `O(logn)` and then insert the element at the correct location is `O(n)`?
Similarly, popping an element from an index must be `O(n)` as well.

Comment: Your understanding of the implementation is incorrect. See the docs: http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/implementation.html

Comment: Oh, got it! Thanks! So insertion and deletion, in this case, is just O(log n).

Comment: For a detailed discussion of the time complexity see https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance-scale.html

Answer (score 6):

Insert, remove, get index, bisect right and left, find element inside list, are all log(n) operations. Its similar to treeset and multiset in java and c++, implemented with AVL tree or red black tree.